# FastCGI Timeout even for simple phpinfo()

Tags: php

all of sudden php on my machine is not working. At first I thought something is wrong with the app but its not even working for `phpinfo()` also even a simple `echo` is not working. I have tried increasing the activity timeout also but it did not help. Issue looks something else but don't know whats that.

**My PHP file:**

[image]

**Activity Timeout:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Does it take 60 seconds to return that response as well?

Comment: Yes. sometime it took 90+ seconds and failed.

Comment: Strange. Does the same happen if you execute the script via the CLI? Must you absolutely use IIS?

Comment: not sure but that is not doing anything. I tried `php -f phpinfo.php > res.html` command but this is not returning anything.

Comment: Returning nothing, as in, the output is not directed to res.html? If so, it seems like there's something wrong with your PHP installation

Comment: After struggling for many days I finally managed to find the issue, it was the `whitespace` in the PHP path so I removed the space from directory and updated the `Handler Mapping` in `IIS` and it started working. Don't know how it was working till few days back :|